# How to make app release compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement Google Error

Tags: android, apk, 64-bit, google-play-console

I apply this ndk filter and then I analyze this apk, lib folder only shows two folders x86 and armeabi-v7a why this not generating folders for 64bit what is wrong

```
defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.iqvis.com.buenosdias"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 101
            versionName "10.1"
            multiDexEnabled true
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    //        jackOptions {
    //            enabled true
    //        }
            dexOptions {
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }
        }
```

Comment: What libraries are in the `lib` folder? If they were imported from outside the project, you will need to find their sources and get 64-bit versions.

Comment: x86-->libsinch-android-rtc.so
armeabi-v7a-->libsinch-android-rtc.so

These libraries are in the lib folder

Comment: where do you get these libraries? Are you building them from source (probably C or C++ files), or including them from some .aar or from local module (files on disk) where the `armeabi-v7a/libsinch-android-rtc.so` file is included? The android tools can't produce 64 bit library from 32 bit library file, it has to be built from the sources. If you have the sources, then your build configuration of the library is wrong, not producing 64b version of library. If you have only binaries of the library, without sources, you have to ask original developer of the library for the 64b versions.

Comment: BTW if you are building from sources, and you never built 64b version of your library before, do extensively test the new 64b version, because you may have tricky bugs in the C/C++/... source producing 32b native code which works, but breaks when the same source is used to produce 64b native code. Depending how "clean" and high quality is the source code of library, producing 64b version may be as simple as editing the build config of the project, or rewrite/fixing of sources for several weeks to make 64b binary work...